# Market neutral without short selling

Tags: strategy, short-selling, market-neutral

Would it be possible to design a market neutral strategy without short selling?

According to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marketneutral.asp):

> Market-neutral strategies are often attained by taking matching long
>   and short positions in different stocks...

According to [here](https://seekingalpha.com/article/2801525-how-to-design-a-market-neutral-portfolio):

> Market Neutral investing is also possible without (...) short
>   selling

How is this possible?

Comment: Cash :) To find a less trivial example what do you mean with market neutral, with respect to what market index / asset class?

Comment: If you're thinking about equity investing and define market neutral as $\beta = 0$ you could invest in negative beta stocks.

Comment: Cash is market neutral. You can also use derivatives which allow to be (approximately) market-neutral if the strategy is well-constructed (such as Futures, options, or inverse ETFs). You can also perform statistical analysis to identify stocks with negative beta.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw What do you mean 'cash'?

Comment: Basically your local currency invested in some bank deposit or very short-term monetary instrument which yield interest close to risk-free. That is not exposed to market variations.